# Conflicting Eigenvalue solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a simple matrix:

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc}
      3&2&3\\
      0&0&2\\
      0&2&0
    \end{array}
\right] $$

And once I try to find the characteristic polynomial:

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc}
      \lambda-3&-2&-3\\
      0&\lambda&-2\\
      0&-2&\lambda
    \end{array}
\right] $$

I'm left with:

$$    \lambda^2(\lambda-3)  $$

However online calculators suggest a charecteristic polynomial of:

$$    −\lambda^3+3\lambda^2+4\lambda−12 $$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How did you get $\lambda^2(\lambda-3)$? -2(-2) isn't 0

Comment: Multiplying down the diagonal.

Comment: err... multiplying down the diagonal? WHY? Do you know how to compute a determinant?

Comment: Oh... Right, so that only works with an upper or lower triangluar matrix, correct?

Comment: ^Right, multiplying down the diagonal works because the zeroes cancel other stuff out. you are really finding the determinant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a simple mistake in computing the determinant. To see the computation,

$$c_A(\lambda) = (\lambda -3)(\lambda^2 - 4) + 2(0) + 3(0) = \lambda^3 - 3\lambda^2 -4\lambda + 12$$ Which differs from wolfram alpha's answer by a sign, so the eigenvalues (roots) are still the same. Your computation coincides with that of an upper triangular matrix.